# SQL Server Return Rows Where Field Changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, record

I have a table with 3 values.

```
ID     AuditDateTime       UpdateType
12     12-15-2015 18:09    1
45     12-04-2015 17:41    0
75     12-21-2015 04:26    0
12     12-17-2015 07:43    0
35     12-01-2015 05:36    1
45     12-15-2015 04:35    0
```

I'm trying to return only records where the `UpdateType` has changed from `AuditDateTime` based on the IDs. So in this example, ID 12 changes from the 12-15 entry to the 12-17 entry. I would want that record returned. There will be multiple instances of ID 12, and I need all records returned where an ID's `UpdateType` has changed from its previous entry. I tried adding a `row_number` but it didn't insert sequentially because the records are not in the table in order. I've done a ton of searching with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a CTE it is possible to find the previous record based upon the order of the AuditDateTime

```
WITH CTEData AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AuditDateTime) [ROWNUM], *
FROM @tmpTable)
SELECT A.ID, A.AuditDateTime, A.UpdateType 
FROM CTEData A INNER JOIN CTEData B 
        ON  (A.ROWNUM - 1) = B.ROWNUM AND 
            A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.UpdateType <> B.UpdateType
```

The Inner Join back onto the CTE will give in one query both the current record (Table Alias A) and previous row (Table Alias B).

Comment: This will still return ID 12 when there's a row with date 12-16-2015 and update type 0 for ID 12.

Comment: It should return the ID of 12 since the record on 12-15-2015 has an update type of 1.  The data returned would be for this new record.

Comment: Try inserting a row with date: 12-16-2015, update type: 0 and ID 12.. In that case It will still return ID 12, which is not asked to do so. (_I need all records returned where an ID's UpdateType has changed from its previous entry_)

Comment: The update type has changed from the previous entry, the first and second entries for ID 12 are changed.  The first entry is a 1 and the second entry is a 0, that is the record that is being returned.  It doesn't say for the last entry, but the previous entry.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're trying to do I believe

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    T1.AuditDateTime,
    T1.UpdateType
FROM
    dbo.My_Table T1
INNER JOIN dbo.My_Table T2 ON
    T2.ID = T1.ID AND
    T2.UpdateType <> T1.UpdateType AND
    T2.AuditDateTime < T1.AuditDateTime
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.My_Table T3 ON
    T3.ID = T1.ID AND
    T3.AuditDateTime < T1.AuditDateTime AND
    T3.AuditDateTime > T2.AuditDateTime
WHERE
    T3.ID IS NULL
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    T1.AuditDateTime,
    T1.UpdateType
FROM
    dbo.My_Table T1
INNER JOIN dbo.My_Table T2 ON
    T2.ID = T1.ID AND
    T2.UpdateType <> T1.UpdateType AND
    T2.AuditDateTime < T1.AuditDateTime
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            dbo.My_Table T3
        WHERE
            T3.ID = T1.ID AND
            T3.AuditDateTime < T1.AuditDateTime AND
            T3.AuditDateTime > T2.AuditDateTime
    )
```

The basic gist of both queries is that you're looking for rows where an earlier row had a different type and no other rows exist between the two rows (hence, they're sequential). Both queries are logically identical, but might have differing performance.

Also, these queries assume that no two rows will have identical audit times. If that's not the case then you'll need to define what you expect to get when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` window function to find the previous value for the same `ID`.  Now you can pick only those rows that introduce a change:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  lag(UpdateType) over (
                  partition by ID
                  order by AuditDateTime) as prev_updatetype
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) sub
where   prev_updatetype <> updatetype
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39281c/2/0)

Comment: @Andomar We are not sure which version of SQL Server was used. Please specify that the LAG function is available in SQL Server 2012 and newer versions.